# Java: lists, bufferedScanner and Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I keep getting the error message  `Error: java.lang.NullPointerException at runtime`.  Obviously I understand that this shows when I am referencing some variable that has a null value when it should have some value.  Thought it best to show you the code so I can put it into context.

```
public class MarathonAdmin
{
   private List<Runner> runners;


   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class MarathonAdmin
    */
   public MarathonAdmin()
   {
      // initialise instance variables
      List<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
   }

    public void readInRunners()
   {
      String pathName = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
      File aFile = new File(pathName);
      Scanner bufferedScanner = null;

      try 
      {
         String runnerName;
         int runnerAge;
         String ageGroup;
         Scanner lineScanner;
         String currentLine;
         bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile)));
         while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
         {
            currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
            lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
            runnerName = lineScanner.next();
            runnerAge = lineScanner.nextInt();

            Runner runnerObject = new Runner();

            if (runnerAge < 18)
            {
               ageGroup = "junior";
               runnerObject.setAgeGroup(ageGroup);
            }
            else
            if (runnerAge > 54)
            {
               ageGroup = "senior";
               runnerObject.setAgeGroup(ageGroup);
            }
            else
            {
               ageGroup = "standard";
               runnerObject.setAgeGroup(ageGroup);
            }

            runnerObject.setName(runnerName);

            runners.add(runnerObject);


         }
      }

      catch (Exception anException)
      {
         System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
      }

      finally
      {
         try
         {
            bufferedScanner.close();
         }

         catch (Exception anException)
         {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
         }
      }
   }
```

The test code to create an instance of the class is:

```
MarathonAdmin ma = new MarathonAdmin();
ma.readInRunners();
```

There is a class in use called `Runners` which is already set up with its protocols.  The class compiles but the `ma.readInRunner();` message ends in an error.  The text file that the program is to run from has no errors.

I'm somewhat new to programming and so find it hard to troubleshoot issues.  Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: It does not say, the error message literally says:

Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

This is part of the problem, if I knew what line it was on then I could try and figure it out but I'm clueless :(

Comment: Put the full stack trace here. It has line numbers and all the methods being called at the time of the error.

Comment: Also debugging tips: Insert print statements for all the places you could get an error. For example `String pathName = OUFileChooser.getFilename();` and `File aFile = new File(pathName);`. This allows you to see where your program is terminating and which variables are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor it should be

```
public MarathonAdmin()
{
  // initialise instance variables
   this.runners = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and not

```
public MarathonAdmin()
{
   // initialise instance variables
   List<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have made a Try-catch block, but in the catch part you are **not printing the stacktrace**, see:

```
  catch (Exception anException)
  {
     System.out.println("Error: " + anException); // just prints: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
  }
```

Improve this catch block for debugging, for example like this:

```
  catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); //prints the full stacktrace
  }
```

Now you should get a full stacktrace that also shows you the line number and you will be able to debug it yourself ;-)

In fact you probably should remove that try-catch blocks at all.